# Kind of platformer game in Spritekit

Tags: sprite-kit, game-physics

I read that using a physics engine can be the cause of many problems in programming platformer type of games.

I am making something similar to the platformer game(not a classic platformer).

- Game will have a platforms, but not many.
- Game will **not** have moving platforms
- Game will **not** have slopes
- Game will have ladders
- Hero can shoot the enemies
- Hero can jump
- Hero can access ladders from the air

I have to choose between physics engine and tile tehnique...

The first problems I can think of are:

1. problem with physics engine and the ladders because physics rules are applied to hero and his movement,so I guess it would be hard to get him on the ladders while his physicsBody.dynamic property is set to YES.
2. problem with the tile tehnique - how to make hero falling from the ledge(while running) with an realistic arc (when we use physics this is done by engine itself...)?

And the main problem, based on the type of the game I am making, is, sholud I combine tiles tehinque(let's say for hero's moving) and physics engine for collision detection, and shooting enemies?

I know there are a lot of questions about this subject, but I must start from something...

Tnx in advance

Comment: I suggest you read into SK physics and make a few tests. These questions aren't suitable for SO, they are too broad and to a large degree based on opinions. Collision handling with ladders should not be an issue when using collision bitmasks and possibly collision delegate methods to change collision behavior while on a ladder. Arcing through gravity is trivial, using physics or not. The combination of tilemap & physics is certainly doable. Ultimately the decision is yours, there's no definite answer here.

Comment: Thanks LearnCocos2D, I was hoping you gonna answer. I have read your article about this, and a few more, but decided to ask, because I dont want to get into trouble from the very beginning.

Comment: And remember that physics in a game engine like SpriteKit isn't an all or nothing proposition. You can use it for contact detection without letting it resolve collisions, you can do contact or collision detection without gravity, you can do full physics-based behavior for some scene elements and simulate motion yourself for others, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend the physics engine.  It is very straight forward... what you expect is generally what happens.

Run, Jump, Shoot, Fall, etc. - Very easy to do using the physics engine.

Ladders will be problematic but you could set a bool flag that lets you know when the ladder and hero are touching, therefore allowing you to exhibit different behaviors depending if this bool is true or not.  Ex.  Make hero not affected by gravity if touching a ladder.

It is very smart that you are planning this out ahead of time and have outlined all of your core requirements.  IMHO, the rest of the requirements will be so easy using the physics engine that it will outweigh additional time spent on the harder part with ladders.

Comment: Hi, meisenman, tnx for the reply. I think I like this idea: "Make hero not affected by gravity if touching a ladder." Thanks everybody for help. I am aware that I need to test and learn much more ,but a little help means a lot when in the beggining.

Answer (score 0):

I would advise against using a physics engine unless you have some complex physical interactions that would be difficult to code by hand, i.e. not just collision detection and basic movement but things reacting realistically to collisions, mechanical objects made of many moving parts and joints, etc. I'm not sure what you mean by a "tile technique", but you can easily code by hand things like a character accelerating towards the ground while maintaining forward momentum (i.e. tracing an arc).

Comment: Tnx for reply Asik. I get it. I need to use physics for the other parts of the game. Enemies, and some obstacles(bouncing etc). For those kind of objects I just need realistic physics engine. I cant do that by hand, and I think there is no need. I just trying to realize, before the start, is the physics engine all I need to complete this kind of game. By tile tehnique, I mean moving hero using tiles and their position on the scene.